# Is there a way to create a component as shown in the image below using react material UI

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui, material-design

Is there a way to create a component as shown in the image below using react material UI..?
I am a new student for react and I have to know idea how to create a component like this.
If you can help me, It's mean a lot. Thank You very much.

[image]

Comment: You should add some code of what you have already tried.  But basically you would want to have two inputs, a text input and a select input, then surround them with a Box(or div) and apply css to get the look you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a starting point for you with the screenshot below taken from material UI documentation.

[image]

Link to documentation: https://mui.com/components/text-fields/

You may check out the source code in the link above to see how they implement it.